# Spring boot application to run legacy Spring web application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a use case where there is a legacy web application using Spring bean.xml.
This application runs in Tomcat by deploying the war file and manually running the tomcat.

I am working on writing a SpringBoot wrapper on it so as to write direct wrapper over it and easily run it form intellij.

**Spring application context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder />
    
    <import resource="classpath:spring/server/service-context.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:spring/server/client-service-context.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:spring/web/web-context.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:spring/reporting-context.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:spring/reporting-service-context.xml"/>

</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
   <!-- Authentication and Authorization related filters -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>Session Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>web.SessionFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>HTTP Authentication Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.commons.security.filter.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>EffectiveUser Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.commons.security.filter.EffectiveUserFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <!-- Webservice Config -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>webservices</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>web.servlet.RemotingServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>webservices</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webservices/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
  <!-- Spring configuration -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
      </context-param>
      <context-param>
        <param-name>contextInitializerClasses</param-name>
        <param-value>com.config.helper.spring.PropertySourceAppContextInitializer</param-value>
      </context-param>
      <context-param>
        <param-name>configDependentLibraries</param-name>
        <param-value>krypton-light,jarvis-light</param-value>
      </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!--<listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener> -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.hazelcast.web.SessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>web.HazelcastShutdownContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- End of Spring configuration -->
```

**Spring Boot java file**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"web"})
@ImportResource({"classpath*:/spring/application-context.xml"})
//@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/spring/application-context.xml"}, initializers = com.config.helper.spring.PropertySourceAppContextInitializer.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootMainAppn {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(SpringBootMainAppn.class, args);
        }

        public WebXmlBridge webXmlBridge() {
            return new WebXmlBridge();
        }
    }
```

**WebXMLBridge file is as**

```
/**
 * Implementation of {@link ServletContextInitializer} to register the servlets, listeners and filters defined
 * in the application's web.xml on startup.
 *
 * TODO servlets' init-params are not supported
 * TODO filters are not registered
 */
@Component
public class WebXmlBridge implements ServletContextInitializer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebXmlBridge.class);

    private static final String WEB_XML_PATH = "/src/modules/web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml";

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {
        WebXml webXml = parseWebXml(servletContext);

        registerServlets(webXml, servletContext);
        registerFilters(webXml, servletContext);
        registerListeners(webXml, servletContext);
    }

    private WebXml parseWebXml(ServletContext servletContext) {
        URL resource;
        FileInputStream filestream;

        try {
            filestream = new FileInputStream(WEB_XML_PATH);
            resource = servletContext.getResource(WEB_XML_PATH);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        WebXml webXml = new WebXml();

        WebXmlParser parser = new WebXmlParser(false, false, false);
        parser.setClassLoader(WebXmlBridge.class.getClassLoader());

        try (InputStream is = filestream) {
            boolean success = parser.parseWebXml(new InputSource(is), webXml, false);
            if (!success) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Error parsing " + WEB_XML_PATH);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Error reading " + WEB_XML_PATH, e);
        }

        return webXml;
    }

    /**
     * It reads servlets defined in web.xml and registers them into the application.
     */
    private void registerServlets(WebXml webXml, ServletContext servletContext) {
        Map<String, String> servletMappings = webXml.getServletMappings();

        for (ServletDef def :  webXml.getServlets().values()) {
            String servletName = def.getServletName();

            List<String> mappings = findMappings(servletMappings, servletName);

            if (mappings.isEmpty()) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Not mapping defined for " + servletName);
            }

            ServletRegistration.Dynamic reg = servletContext.addServlet(servletName, def.getServletClass());
            for (String mapping : mappings) {
                reg.addMapping(mapping);
            }

            LOGGER.info("Registered servlet with name [{}] Class[{}] Mappings[{}]", servletName, def.getServletClass(),
                    mappings);
        }
    }

    private List<String> findMappings(Map<String, String> servletMappings, String servletName) {
        List<String> mappings = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> mapping : servletMappings.entrySet()) {
            if (mapping.getValue().equals(servletName)) {
                mappings.add(mapping.getKey());
            }
        }

        return mappings;
    }

    /**
     * Method to read filters defined in web.xml and to register them into the application.
     */
    private void registerFilters(WebXml webXml, ServletContext servletContext) {
        LOGGER.info("Filters are not supported");
    }

    /**
     * It reads listeners defined in web.xml and registers them into the application.
     */
    private void registerListeners(WebXml webXml, ServletContext servletContext) {
        for (String listener : webXml.getListeners()) {
            servletContext.addListener(listener);
            LOGGER.info("Registered listener class [{}]", listener);
        }
    }

}
```

***While running this application from intellij what error i am seeing is that its not able to read the beans defined in application-context.xml.
The beans in the spring application xml file are not picked at all.***

Comment: Are there any errors? Anything in the INFO logs?